# Prove that for any connected graph $G$ there exists a graph $H$ such that $G\cong Z[H]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Prove that for any connected graph $G$ there exists a graph $H$ such that $G\cong Z[H]$ (are isomorphic), where $Z[H]$ denotes the graph induced by the center of $H$.

**Attempt:**

Something like:

[image]

Comment: What is the center of $H?$

Comment: It would be $G$, so $G\cong G$. The center of a graph is the set of all vertices of minimum eccentricity,

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you would like to know? Your proof (that is, the proof suggested by the picture) is correct.

Comment: What I want to know, is how to formalize what I have in the image?